# Python "mask = greater(array(mfout), 0.0)" works on 64-bit, not on 32-bit (numpy/scipy)

Tags: python, linux, numpy, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am new to Python and I'm trying to adapt and modernize some old Python 2.4 scripts on a 64-bit Linux platform (CentOS 5.8), including moving the scripts from the existing 64-bit platform to 32-bit (CentOS 5.8).  I've managed to fix the dependency issues but one of the scripts breaks at the following statement:

```
mask = greater(array(mfout), 0.0)
```

The error is "TypeError: function not supported for these types, and can't coerce to supported types".  There is no problem on 64-bit.

Any ideas on why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: My guess is the system throwing TypeError is running python 3 and the one that doesn't is older.

Comment: Thanks - checked that, "Python 2.4.3..."

Comment: If I can get the scripts working, the next step is to move to Python-3.

Comment: What `dtype` is `mfout`?  (i.e. what do you get when you do `print array(mfout).dtype`)

Comment: The result is "AttributeError: dtype" - what should that be telling me?